# Injecting services into listener classes

Tags: php, symfony

I seem to be missing a step that I haven't been able to identify when trying to inject a service into my listener.

Here's my services.xmlL

```
<services>
    <!-- Activity logger -->
    <service id="myapp.activity_logger" class="My\AppBundle\Api\ActivityLogger">
    </service>
    <!-- Activity events -->
    <service id="myapp.activity.logged_in" class="My\AppBundle\Listener\ActivityListener">
        <argument type="service" id="myapp.activity_logger" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onLoggedIn" priority="254" />
    </service>
    ...
```

The listener class itself:

```
namespace My\AppBundle\Listener;

use My\AppBundle\Api\ActivityLogger;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class ActivityListener
{
    protected $activityLogger;

    public function __construct(ActivityLogger $al)
    {
        $this->activityLogger = $al;
    }

    public function onLoggedIn(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Log activity data

    }
```

The error I receive when I trigger the event:

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
My\AppBundle\Listener\ActivityListener::__construct() must be an instance of 
My\AppBundle\Api\ActivityLogger, none given, called in 
/var/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2739 and defined in 
/var/www/src/My/AppBundle/Listener/ActivityListener.php line 18
```

I can't seem to isolate what I'm doing wrong to inject a service, as I believe I'm following the correct steps from the manual.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just didn't reset the cache. I suppose the flow was as follows:

1. You created the `ActivityListener` class without the constructor
2. Described service in config without injecting the logger service
3. Flushed the cache
4. Added constructor and injected Logger service in config, but forgot to flush cache

Comment: Hmm.. nope, although your theory maybe correct I am still getting the same error after clearing the cache and attempting to load